# How to Change GridView row color based on condition in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, gridview

I want to change a particular row color of gridview based on some condition, i am using ASP.NET with c#.
Here is the sample Output:
[image: Sample Output]

```
 <cc1:PagingGridView ID="TaskNameGrid"
            runat="server"
            AllowPaging="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CssClass="SearchResultsTable"
            ShowHeader="true"
            virtualitemcount1="-1"
            OnRowdatabound="TaskNameGrid_Rowdatabound"
            OnRowCancelingEdit="TaskNameGrid_RowCancelingEdit" 
            OnRowEditing="TaskNameGrid_RowEditing" 
            OnRowUpdating="TaskNameGrid_RowUpdating"
             Width="400px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternate" />
        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" />
        <RowStyle />
        <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Task Name" DataField="BusinessIdentifier" SortExpression="BusinessIdentifier" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SLA" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="sno">
              <EditItemTemplate>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="SlaVariationTextBox" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("SLA") %>'></asp:TextBox>
              </EditItemTemplate>
              <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SLA", "not set") %>'></asp:Label>  
              </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
        </Columns>
     </cc1:PagingGridView>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

as Tim said, use RowDataBound

Html:

```
            <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="TaskNameGrid"
        runat="server"
        AllowPaging="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CssClass="SearchResultsTable"
        virtualitemcount1="-1"
         Width="400px" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" 
                onrowdatabound="TaskNameGrid_RowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternate" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BusinessIdentifier" HeaderText="BusinessIdentifier" 
                SortExpression="BusinessIdentifier" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SLA" HeaderText="SLA" SortExpression="SLA" />
        </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" />
    <RowStyle />

    </asp:GridView>


            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="Get" 
                TypeName="DataForGrid">
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>


        </div>
```

Aspx Events

```
    protected void TaskNameGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var d = (DataStructure)e.Row.DataItem;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.SLA))
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

        }
    }
}
```

Data Layer Classes

```
    public class DataStructure
{
    public string BusinessIdentifier { get; set; }

    public string SLA { get; set; }

    public DataStructure()
    {


    }
}

public class DataForGrid
{
    public DataForGrid()
    {
        this.Stuff = new List<DataStructure>();

        this.Stuff.Add(new DataStructure { BusinessIdentifier = "TaskName1", SLA = "1.2" });
        this.Stuff.Add(new DataStructure { BusinessIdentifier = "Taskname2", SLA = null });
        this.Stuff.Add(new DataStructure { BusinessIdentifier = "TaskName3", SLA = "1.2" });
        this.Stuff.Add(new DataStructure { BusinessIdentifier = "TaskName4", SLA = "1.2" });
        this.Stuff.Add(new DataStructure { BusinessIdentifier = "TaskName5", SLA = "1.2" });

    }
    public List<DataStructure> Stuff { get; set; }

    public List<DataStructure> Get()
    {




        return this.Stuff;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is an ASP.NET grid

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RowDataBound` event. You can use the rows [`DataItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx) to get the underlying `DataSource`:

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // modify it accoording to your datasource, use the debugger if you're not sure
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        // just an example:
        bool redCondition = row.Field<string>("SomColumn") == "Some Value";
        e.Row.BackColor = redCondition ? Color.Red : GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
    }
}
```